# How to transpose a DataFrame based on values present in two different columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have A DataFrame, an example of which is shared below -

```
Index   Name    Value
3        A       xyz
4        B       asd
5        C       cvz
6        D       red
7        E       fsd
3        A       gfd
4        B       gsa
5        C       hgd
6        D       ewr
7        E       dgs
```

**Expected Output**

```
A      B      C      D      E
xyz   asd    cvz    red    fsd
gfd   gsa    hgd    ewr    dgs
```

The reason behind this expected output is we have the value in `Index` column repeated and the column names are present in `Name`. I have tried using `groupby` and `transpose` but unable to get the expected output.

**EDIT 1**

There might be following cases as well

```
Index   Name    Value
3        A       xyz
4        B       asd
6        D       red
7        E       fsd
3        A       gfd
4        B       gsa
5        C       hgd
6        D       ewr
7        E       dgs
3        A       dfd
4        B       dsa
5        C       dgd
6        D       dwr
```

**Expected Output**

```
A      B      C      D      E
xyz   asd           red    fsd
gfd   gsa    hgd    ewr    dgs
dfd   dsa    dgd    dwr
```

**EDIT 2**

**Explanation** : There is a repeating list of values in column `Index`, whenever there is a negative change/no change (index value in the next row becomes less than or equal to the previous row), it means the value corresponding is for the next row.
In second sample provided, the values for columns A, B, D and E is present for the first repeating occurence of an index, and the last occurence of these repeating occurences doesn't have `E`, hence the rows should be as that of **Expected Output**

Thanks !

Comment: Hey guys, I have made a change to the sample dataframe. I am really apologetic, I didn't cover this issue prior. Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: There can be no value present for a particular column .

Comment: EDIT 2 - Provided explanation regarding the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked perfectly for my case where there can be missing values by detecting change point in the column `Index`.

There might be a more Pythonic way but this solution works suitably for the given problem.

1. Find the Change Point Indices

```
df['Index'] = df['Index'].diff()
indices=df[df['Index']<0].index
```

2. For each temporary DataFrame, create a dictionary that will help in transpose and hence create a DataFrame.

```
final_list=[]
temp_df=df[0:indices[0]]
final_list.append(dict(zip(temp_df.loc[:,"Name"].values, temp_df.loc[:,"Value"].values)))
for i in range(0,len(indices)):
    if(i<len(indices)-1):
        temp_df=df[indices[i]:indices[i+1]]
    else:
        temp_df=df[indices[i]:]
    final_list.append(dict(zip(temp_df.loc[:,"Name"].values, temp_df.loc[:,"Value"].values)))
final_df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(final_list)
```

**Output**

```
    A   B   D   E   C
0   xyz asd red fsd NaN
1   gfd gsa ewr dgs hgd
2   dfd dsa dwr NaN dgd
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
df['Index'] = df.groupby(['Index', 'Name'])['Index'].cumcount()
df.pivot(index='Index', columns='Name', values='Value').reset_index(drop=True)
#output
Name    A   B   C   D   E
0       xyz asd cvz red fsd
1       gfd gsa hgd ewr dgs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [52]: df
Out[52]:
   Index Name Value
0      3    A   xyz
1      4    B   asd
2      5    C   cvz
3      6    D   red
4      7    E   fsd
5      3    A   gfd
6      4    B   gsa
7      5    C   hgd
8      6    D   ewr
9      7    E   dgs

In [53]: df.groupby("Name").agg({'Value':list}).T.apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[53]:
Name    A    B    C    D    E
0     xyz  asd  cvz  red  fsd
1     gfd  gsa  hgd  ewr  dgs
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Terry's solution. I only added `fillna` method.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {'Index': [3, 4,
                      5, 6,
                      7, 3,
                      4, 5,
                      6, 7,
                      3, 4,
                      5, 6],
            'Name': ['A', 'B',
                     'C', 'D',
                     'E', 'A',
                     'B', 'C',
                     'D', 'E',
                     'A', 'B',
                     'C', 'D'],
            'Value': ['xyz', 'asd',
                      'cvz', 'red',
                      'fsd', 'gfd',
                      'gsa', 'hgd',
                      'ewr', 'dgs',
                      'dfd', 'dsa',
                      'dgd', 'dwr']}

    df = DataFrame(data, columns=['Index',
                                  'Name',
                                  'Value'])

    df['Index'] = df.groupby(['Index', 'Name'])['Index'].cumcount()

    print(df.pivot(index='Index',
                   columns='Name',
                   values='Value').reset_index(drop=True).fillna(''))
```

Output:

```
Name    A    B    C    D    E
0     xyz  asd  cvz  red  fsd
1     gfd  gsa  hgd  ewr  dgs
2     dfd  dsa  dgd  dwr
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. But, it doesn't provide correct output for `data = {'Index': [3, 4,6,7, 3,4, 5,6, 7,3, 4,5, 6],
'Name': ['A', 'B','D','E', 'A','B', 'C','D', 'E','A', 'B','C', 'D'],
'Value': ['xyz', 'asd','red','fsd', 'gfd','gsa', 'hgd','ewr', 'dgs','dfd', 'dsa','dgd', 'dwr']}`. Here `C` is missing in the first row itself but it is shuffling the data.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: `DataFrame({"A":['xyz','gfd','dfd'],"B":['asd','gsa','dsa'],"C":['','hgd','dgd'],"D":['red','ewr','dwr'],"F":["fsd","dgs",""]})`. Since `C` is missing in the first occurence of 3-7, In the next row, all are present but in the final row `E` is missing